# How to separate ControlTemplate.Triggers from ControlTemplate in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new in WPF. I need to separate this xaml code from ControlTemplate. 
This is my original code.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="AddImgBtnTemplate" TargetType="Button" >
<Grid>
  <Border  Name="border" Height="25" Width="25"/>
  <Image Name="Normal"     Source="/UILibrary;component/Themes/Default/Images/Add.png" Height="18" Width="18"/>
  <Image Name="Pressed" Source="/UILibrary;component/Themes/Default/Images/Add.png" Opacity="0.7" Visibility="Hidden" Height="18" Width="18"/>
  <Image Name="Disabled" Source="/UILibrary;component/Themes/Default/Images/Add.png" Opacity="0.3"  Visibility="Hidden" Height="18" Width="18"/>
</Grid>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter TargetName="Pressed" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
  </Trigger>
  <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
    <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter TargetName="Disabled" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
  </Trigger>
  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="3" />
    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF948A54" />
  </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Need to seprate code this code. This code is repeated code need to define only ones.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter TargetName="Pressed" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
  </Trigger>
  <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
    <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter TargetName="Disabled" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
  </Trigger>
  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="3" />
    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF948A54"   />
  </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place this code with triggers into the `Style`, like this.

```
<Style x:Key="myButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And you can use this style in the `Template` or other buttons.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource myButton}"/>
```

Comment: but TargetName property cannot be set on a Style Setter.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've missed that. Can you explain the reasons of separating this code? I hope this helps to find the solution.

Comment: #bars222: reasons is i have lot of ControlTemplate and thire <ControlTemplate.Triggers> </ControlTemplate.Triggers> is same all ControlTemplate so we need to avoid repeated code.

Comment: So if all these ControlTemplates differs only with images I suggest you can try to use one ControlTemplate with some `Bindings` for images.